# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, compiler-errors

I will post an answer to an error I had since I found the solution.

I received the error in asp.net: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'

```
// Old line
// rpOutils.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].Select("rnco_lang = '" + ddlLang.SelectedValue + "'");
// rpOutils.DataSource = ds; // New line that caused the error. I just wanted to pass a DataSet
rpOutils.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].Select(); // New line with the solution.
rpOutils.DataBind();

protected void rpOutils_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                DataRow row = (DataRow)e.Item.DataItem; // I received the System.InvalidCastException
```

...

The Dataset returned a DataRowView and the line that caused the problem expected a DataRow.

I searched for the solution and didn't find, so I found it and posted my solution. Thanks.

Comment: As the error stated: DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

Answer (score 6):

When databinding to a DataTable, the databinding engine will call the DataTable's `IListSource` implementation and bind to its `DataView`.

Since DataViews hold DataRowView objects and not DataRows, you cannot cast the bound objects directly to DataRow.
Instead, you need to cast to `DataRowView`, then get the `Row` property.

For a more detailed explanation of why this happens, see [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/binding-to-lists-of-datarows.html).

Answer (score 0):

use dynamic data . it fill be filled properties.

```
    private void GvRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            dynamic data = e.Row.DataItem;
            TextBox txtType = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtbox");
            if (data.IsCheked)
            {
                txtType.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```